# How to sort dictionary with string and int value by int only

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

For example from dictionary

```
{"Name": "Mark","country": "England", "Age":15,

"Name": "Tom","country": "Poland", "Age":10,

"Name": "Sam","country": "USA", "Age":19,

"Name": "Bob","country": "Italy", "Age":17}
```

I want to get

```
{"Name": "Tom","country": "Poland", "Age":10,

"Name": "Mark","country": "England", "Age":15,

"Name": "Bob","country": "Italy", "Age":17,

"Name": "Sam","country": "USA", "Age":19,}
```

Code like this is not helping

```
for key, value in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda item: int(item[0]))
```

Comment: This is not valid Python, or at least not what you expect

Comment: Your example is NOT a dictionnary, as we see duplicate keys

Comment: @steve did you mean to have a list of dictionaries?

Comment: What's the sort condition - I assume by age, right?

Comment: Does this solves your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant to have a list of dicts like this:

```py
a = [{"Name": "Tom","country": "Poland", "Age":10},
     {"Name": "Mark","country": "England", "Age":15},
     {"Name": "Bob","country": "Italy", "Age":17},
     {"Name": "Sam","country": "USA", "Age":19}]
```

The most obvious answer with this dataset would be:

```py
sorted(a, key=lambda x:x["Age"])
```

For the more general case of sorting on *all* integer values you could use something like:

```py
sorted(a, key=lambda x: sum(v for v in x.values() if isinstance(v, int)))
```

although depending on your usecase checking for `int` might be too narrow a criterion.  This solution first sums up all ints in the dict `(v for v in x.values() if isinstance(v, int))` and then sorts on that sum.